# Request permission before Logback loads configuration (and creates log file)

Tags: android, logback, android-permissions

I'm using [Logback for Android](https://github.com/tony19/logback-android) to write my app's logs in external storage file. My app is being executed in Android M so I need to request permission to the user to write in that file (WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).

However, when app is launched, Logback reads config file (`src/main/assets/logback.xml`) and tries to create the log file (in this case, it's located in `/sdcard/logback/myapp` dir), before user has given the permission for that, so it throws a permission denied error.

Is there any way to tell Logback when to load the logging configuration? I need to force Logback to "reset" the configuration when permission is given by the user, so it has permission to create the file.

**logback.xml**

```
<configuration>
    <property name="LOG_DIR" value="/sdcard/logback/myapp"/>

    <appender name="FILE" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%dateStr [%thread] %-5level %logger{35} - %msg %n</pattern>
        </encoder>

        <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
            <fileNamePattern>${LOG_DIR}/myapp.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</fileNamePattern>
            <maxHistory>7</maxHistory>
        </rollingPolicy>
    </appender>

    <appender name="LOGCAT" class="ch.qos.logback.classic.android.LogcatAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>%msg</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="DEBUG">
        <appender-ref ref="FILE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="LOGCAT"/>
    </root>

</configuration>
```

Comment: i would suggest that you put this question on their github issues. https://github.com/tony19/logback-android/issues

Comment: Thank you @YamenNassif. I will do it. I found a provisional solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution. In `onRequestPermissionResult` method, when user has given the permission to write to external storage, I'm reloading Logback configuration with this code:

```
LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
loggerContext.reset();
ContextInitializer ci = new ContextInitializer(loggerContext);
ci.autoConfig();
```

Now, the file is created and everything is working properly.

Comment: just out of curiosity you said 'reloading Logback' but as you described i think you need to initiate it there.

Comment: Yes, of course. But actually when app is launched, it is automatically initialized, so the file can't be created (permission denied).With this code, I re-initialize it.

Comment: Am I right with my assumption, that you gonna loose all log statements made before resetting the Logger Context...? 
If yes you could "cache" them in internal sd card location, and after granted permissions to external storage, you could change the location to external...?